# What is this invisible character icon in Pages?

Tags: pages

I enabled 'show invisibles' on a docx that has been converted from pdf and this icon appears at several places:

[image]

I cannot get rid of it. What is this icon? What's its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple's [official documentation](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23650?locale=en_US), that symbol denotes a layout break.

These allow you to change the layout anywhere on the page (for example, a one-column title then a two-column title).

The reason you can't remove it is because it's part of the layout of the document. You could try applying a default style to the text that is part of the layout break (such as "body text").